# Recovery data from corrupted encrypted partition

Tags: partition, data-recovery, ext4, disk, luks

I accidentally overwritten 3.4 gb (exactly first 3407725056 bytes) used dd command on my external 1TB disk with LUKS encryption.

The disk was prepared exactly as described this tutorial:

https://www.loganmarchione.com/2015/05/encrypted-external-drive-with-luks/

I have backup the LUKS header (and dump of master key)

How restore any data ? in this case is the directory structure recoverable?

Comment: Don't waste your time.

Comment: Did you make regular backups of any data files you value?

Comment: MichaelBay, WHY ? TestDisk should restore partition table from backup on at the end of disk. then LUKS header might be restored from backup and partition might be repair by e2fsck if backup superblock is not overwritten. it is impossible ?